# Add a divider between subcategories and products in WooCommerce loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I need to add divider line or Elementor template between products and subcategories in main category WooCommerce.

I separated it but I cannot add divider

I used this code with Elementor template short code, but it was separated by white space

```php
add_action( 'init', 'move_subcat_lis' );
function move_subcat_lis() {
    // Remove the subcat <li>s from the old location.
    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_product_loop_start', 'woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories' );

    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'msc_product_loop_start', 40 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'msc_maybe_show_product_subcategories', 50 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'msc_product_loop_end', 60 );
}

/**
* Conditonally start the product loop with a <ul> contaner if subcats exist.
*/
function msc_product_loop_start() {
    $subcategories = woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories();

    if ( $subcategories ) {
        woocommerce_product_loop_start();
    }
}

/**
* Print the subcat <li>s in our new location.
*/
function msc_maybe_show_product_subcategories() {
    echo woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories();
}

/**
* Conditonally end the product loop with a </ul> if subcats exist.
*/
function msc_product_loop_end() {
    get_header();

    echo do_shortcode('[elementor-template id="2808"]'); 

    $subcategories = woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories();

    if ( $subcategories ) {
        woocommerce_product_loop_end();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a full working code example. And please explain what kind of divider you need: a visual divider or a `div`? in any way we'll need the working HTML and CSS to help you.

Comment: this is the full code

Comment: the divider is template from elementor

Comment: this is the divider code
 get_header();
echo do_shortcode('[elementor-template id="2808"]');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this Wordpress StackExchange answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/357089/79855), you can use the following simplified version:

```php
// Remove displayed subcategories from product loop
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_product_loop_start', 'woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories' );

// Display subcategories before the product loop
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'display_product_subcategories', 50 );

function display_product_subcategories() {
    $categories = woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories();

    if ( $categories ) {
        printf('<ul class="products categories columns-%d">%s</ul>',
            esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) ), $categories );

        echo '<hr>'; // <== Divider 
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Now you can replace the `<hr>` separator from:

```php
echo '<hr>'; // <== Divider
```

with your shortcode, like:

```php
echo do_shortcode('[elementor-template id="2808"]');
```

Comment: it is working, thanks

Comment: but all css customizations were changed
how can I make subcategories in the center 
and show 2 subcategories in each line in the mobile view